# Position UI to mouse position (Make Tooltip panel follow cursor)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tooltip, mouse-cursor

I made a tooltip panel follow the cursor with

```
void Update () {
    this.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;  
}
```

in the Update function.

The panel "lags" behind, moving to cursor position after quarter of a second, and its kind of annoying
Is there a better way of doing this? Can i somehow "glue" it to the cursor?
Here is how it looks when i move mouse from right to left.[image]

Panel IS under the cursor when mouse is still, it only trails off when moved vigorously.

Comment: Tried it in unity, cannot see any lag. Please share some more info about your app, panel, script.

Comment: If I put 30px30p panel and make it follow the cursor,with simple Input.mousePosition i can easily outrun it my moving mouse fast.

Is it not the case for other people?

I tried making empty project and still have the same problem. I need 30p by 30p panel to always be under the cursor.

Comment: The tooltip panel, is it s UI or a normal GameObject? What do you mean  by slow? Tooltip not where mouse cursor is? I think you should put a screenshot.

Comment: its just Panel object

Comment: Disregard my first comment. I can see the lag when UI panel is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with unity.

While binding mouse position to any gameObject's position, we face lag. This lag is introduced by unity input module's mouse position recording. [Reference1](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/192998/mouse-input-lag.html), [Reference2](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/keeping-an-object-tightly-under-mouse.155546/).

**Work Around :** You can make your own cursor in game and bind it to mouse position(as you're binding the UI panel). The custom cursor object in game will have the same position as the the panel because both of these objects will derive their position from same source. And you'll get a lag free panel. :)

Remember to hide the default cursor.

Comment: Is there any known hack around that?
I guess its not that critical.

Comment: @programmer, I was writing my answer while you edited yours. please don't think otherwise. All that matters is we have solution for this issue. Anyways, We both have same work around for this problem which makes it full-proof ;).

Answer (score 10):

You **can't** assign `Input.mousePosition;` directly to the UI transform. You have to use [`RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html) to convert the mouse position and Canvas to the appropriate position the UI can understand.

After that, you use `Canvas.transform.TransformPoint(result)` to get the final position of the mouse that should be assigned to the UI/Panel position.

This what that code should look like:

```
public Canvas parentCanvas;

public void Start()
{
    Vector2 pos;

    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
        parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, Input.mousePosition,
        parentCanvas.worldCamera,
        out pos);
}

public void Update()
{
    Vector2 movePos;

    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
        parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform,
        Input.mousePosition, parentCanvas.worldCamera,
        out movePos);

    transform.position = parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos);
}
```

Make sure to assign the Canvas to the parentCanvas slot.

**EDIT:**

With the original image in your question, I thought that the UI you are moving is always on the side of cursor. After the linked video, I just realized the problem is that the there is a delay on when the Object moves to the cursor position.

This is a problem with Unity. Unity is currently redesigning the InputSystem to fix this problem. The current workaround is to disable the cursor with `Cursor.visible = false;` then use another image with a cursor icon as the cursor.

Find good cursor online and assign it to the mouseCursor slot texture from the Editor..

```
public Canvas parentCanvas;
public RawImage mouseCursor;

public void Start()
{
    Cursor.visible = false;
}


public void Update()
{
    Vector2 movePos;

    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
        parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform,
        Input.mousePosition, parentCanvas.worldCamera,
        out movePos);

    Vector3 mousePos = parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos);

    //Set fake mouse Cursor
    mouseCursor.transform.position = mousePos;

    //Move the Object/Panel
    transform.position = mousePos;
}
```

---

Finally, you will notice that I don't use `Input.mousePosition` directly to set the UI position. Don't use it. The reason is that when you change the Canvas RenderMode and assign the Camera, `Input.mousePosition` won't work but the `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle` solution should work.

Comment: Same effect, Panel trails after the cursor :(

Comment: it works smoothly on my side. What is your Camera Projection mode? What is Canva's render mode? You Unity version?

Comment: Perspective - Overlay - 5.4.0

Comment: I am using the-same settings and the UI is **always** over the mouse position. This is the proper way to do it and this has been working for me since UI release. I just tested it again and it's working. You are doing something wrong. Select the Panel that you are moving, click the RectTranform, hold shift and click the center to center the anchor. I think that's the problem you have now.

Comment: maybe you dont move it fast enough? or it have something with my mouse being USB one? anyway here is an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cV2tjq51n8

Comment: tried all of it, doesn't make any difference for me

Answer (score 1):

**Unity 2021** - for everyone interested in 2021 in having tooltip (Unity GUI) following a mouse position.

Solution with *RectTransformUtility* posted above does not work or it depends on some canvas setup nuances which are missing from the post.

What just works (tm) in Unity 2021 is following:

Canvas setup:

[image]

Tooltip being a simple UI object (panel or whatever) as child of the canvas, with following setup:

[image]

and with following script attached:

```
tooltip_rect_transform_ref.anchoredPosition = Input.mousePosition / tooltip_parent_canvas.transform.localScale.x;
```

Works in Editor and in build, at different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

*Digging this back up as I had the same quest today.*

Regarding the solution by @zizu_zaza, it does not take into account different aspect ratio (at least when Canvas Scaler screen match ratio is not 1.0 or 0.0). Scaling the mouse position by the canvas scale only works for different resolutions at the same aspect.

To consider both resolution and aspect in the mouse position scaling, do:

```
Vector2 mergedFactors = new Vector2(
      (canvas.transform as RectTransform).sizeDelta.x / Screen.width,
      (canvas.transform as RectTransform).sizeDelta.y / Screen.height);
//x and y -> *= (RefX/ScreenWidth) * (CanvasWidth/RefX)
tooltip.anchoredPosition = mousePos * mergedFactors;

//Short maths explanation:
//CanvasScaler scaler = GetComponentInParent<CanvasScaler>();
//Vector2 scaleFactors = new Vector2(
//    scaler.referenceResolution.x / Screen.width, 
//    scaler.referenceResolution.y / Screen.height);
//Vector2 aspectFactors = new Vector2(
//    (canvas.transform as RectTransform).sizeDelta.x / scaler.referenceResolution.x,
//    (canvas.transform as RectTransform).sizeDelta.y / scaler.referenceResolution.y);
//Vector2 mergedFactors = scaleFactors * aspectFactors
//
//->scale reference resolution by actual screen resolution
//->scale canvas "size" (which adjusts to aspect) by reference resolution
//->combine both: reference resolution multi & div cancel out
```

This will allow a tooltip (or any other UI object) to follow the mouse at *any* resolution and aspect ratio.