# DragAndDrop UI Functions on World Space Canvas Does Not Work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, 3d

My goal is to create puzzles in which the player has to drag and drop UI elements on a world space canvas. As my game is first person, I wrote code separately that freezes the player's movement, unlocks the cursor from screen center and makes the cursor visible. This code all works fine.

I created a World Space Canvas and adjusted its size to fit the 3D space I want it to fit. I created two images as its children. The Images have a CanvasGroup. The 1st person camera is assigned in the inspector of the canvas as the Event camera.

I used code suggested here by "Programmer": [Position UI to mouse position (Make Tooltip panel follow cursor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802207/position-ui-to-mouse-position-make-tooltip-panel-follow-cursor)

The code I am using: (which is relevant)

```
public RectTransform rectTrans;
public Canvas parentCanvas;

void Start() {
    rectTrans = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    myCanvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();

    Vector2 pos;

    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
        parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform, Input.mousePosition,
        parentCanvas.worldCamera,
        out pos); }

private void Update() {
    Vector2 movePos;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
        parentCanvas.transform as RectTransform,
        Input.mousePosition, parentCanvas.worldCamera,
        out movePos);

        transform.position = parentCanvas.transform.TransformPoint(movePos); }       }
```

I separately assigned the images' Transforms in their Inspectors. However, they both still follow the cursor (perfectly on top of each other). I am trying to figure out how to have them be individually dragged, not both at once.

Comment: well you need to check what the mousedown was over when it went down to check it was an object you want to drag